# How to trigger a Pipeline on branch creation with excluded folders in AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I want to trigger the pipeline in AzureDevOps if I push a commit to master.
I also want it to trigger if I create a new branch in realeases or if I create a new version of the test branch.

I currently have the following trigger configuration in one of my pipelines in Azure DevOps:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    batch: true
    include:
      - master
      - test
      - releases/*
  paths:
    exclude:
      - .azuredevops
      - renovate.json
```

The pipeline now only triggers when I push to master, not when I create a new branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this doc: [Behavior of triggers when new branches are created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003781#behavior-of-triggers-when-new-branches-are-created)

> Here is the behavior when you push a new branch (that matches the branch filters) >to your repository:

> If your pipeline has path filters, it will be triggered only if the new branch has >changes to files that match that path filter.

> If your pipeline does not have path filters, it will be triggered even if there are >no changes in the new branch.

In your case, you have set the path filters in the triggers, it will be triggered only if the new branch has >changes to files that match that path filter.

The behavior you are currently observing is expected(The pipeline now only triggers when I push to master).

To let the new created branch trigger pipeline, you need to remove the path filter.

For example:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - test
      - releases/*
```

**Result:**

[image]